# How can I inherit from Rational (or any class with no constructor)?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I can easily inherit from, say, `String` for example, like this:

```
class MyString < String
  def stuff
    self + ' and stuff'
  end
end

# This works:
MyString.new('things').stuff # => 'things and stuff'
```

But how can I inherit from `Rational`, which has no constructor? For example:

```
def MyRat < Rational
  def inc
    self + 1
  end
end

# I have tried to initialize like this:
MyRat.new(10).inc # => NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for MyRat:Class
MyRat(10).inc # => NoMethodError: undefined method `MyRat' for main:Object
MyRat.send(:initialize, 10).inc  # => TypeError: already initialized class
# ???
# None of it works!
```

I can't find a way to initialize my new class.

Comment: why not writing your own `#initialize` method ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I can't. How would I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own object to be a proxy around `Rational`.

```
class MyRat < BasicObject
  def initialize(value)
    @rational = Rational(value)
  end

  def inc
    @rational + 1
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    @rational.send(name, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

Methods defined in your class will be used, otherwise the class will delegate to the rational instance.

```
r = MyRat.new(10)

# MyRat#inc is used
r.inc
# => (11/1) 

# to_int delegates to Rational
r.to_int
# => 10
```

A partial explanation of because Numeric has no initialize is available in [this thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/96434)

> Looking at the C code, I see that new() exists in Numeric and Float,
>   but it is specifically removed:
>       rb_cInteger = rb_define_class("Integer", rb_cNumeric);
>       rb_undef_alloc_func(rb_cInteger);
>       rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cInteger), "new");
>
> ```
> #....and for floats..
> rb_undef_alloc_func(rb_cFloat);
> rb_undef_method(CLASS_OF(rb_cFloat), "new");
> ```
>
> The ruby source code contains no explanation for the removal of new.
>   That's why I'm wondering what the reasoning behind this was.  It does
>   not seem to be technical limitation in the ruby interpreter.
>   Currently, it does not make much sense to me.

and the reason is because

> It's an internal optimization.  Fixnums do not have to be created and
>   they never have to be GC'ed.  This goes a long way to make math faster
>   than it would be with ordinary objects (at least for Fixnums).

Additional suggestions and alternatives are explained in this article [The Complete Numeric Class](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/019-Complete_Numeric_Class.html).

Comment: This should work, but I'm quite curious why you can't inherit from `Rational`.

Comment: You'll have to undef all the methods [`BasicObject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html) provides: `eql?` and `==` and `!=`

Comment: It works! +1 and accepted. But, I have a question: why does it have to inherit from `BasicObject`? It breaks without it, but I don't see why that is needed...

Comment: I integrated my answer with more internal details about the reason.

Comment: I use `BasicObject` because it's a very simple object with no additional utility methods. It's the perfect candidate for a proxy class.

Comment: Okay, but why do I have to inherit from anything at all? Why can't I just do `class MyRat ... end`?

Comment: If you don't inherit from `BasicObject` you will automatically inherit from `Object` and you will get a bunch of default methods that may conflict (such as `to_s`, `inspect`, etc.). You want those methods to delegate to your Rational instance.

Comment: Better to use the `delegate` lib