# Fixnum undefined method new

Tags: ruby

When I tried fixnum.new is giving undefined method error.

```
Fixnum.new  # undefined method `new' for Fixnum:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Why its give undefined method. What mechanism behind the fixnum class. please explain.

If I want to make some class like fixnum (A class without new method) then what should I do?

I am going with below code but I am feeling its bad code.

```
class TestClass < Fixnum
end
```

When I tried to create new object like below:

```
TestClass.new #undefined method `new' for TestClass:Class
```

is this correct way? or if you have another way please explain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, you are trying to write a class that is not instantiatable using the `new` method. You could borrow the idea from the [`Singleton`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/singleton.rb#L161-L166) module and make the `new` (and `allocate`) method private:

```
class Whatever
  private_class_method :new, :allocate
end

Whatever.new
# NoMethodError: private method `new' called for Whatever:Class
```

Comment: oh we can use singleton module as below:

    require 'singleton'
    class Example
      include Singleton
    end

    Example.new #it gives private method new called for whatever:Class
    a = Example.instance # and we can create a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 2):

As I explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20666939/123527), Fixnum doesn't provide a `.new` method. That's because you expect to create a new Fixnum (or a descendant such as Integer or Float) in the following way

```
1.3
1
```

and because, despite they are objects, there are no multiple instances of a Fixnum. In the same answer I also explained how you can use a proxy class around objects that doesn't offer such initialization.

Here's a code example

```
class MyFixnum < BasicObject
  def initialize(value)
    @fixnum = value
  end

  def inc
    @fixnum + 1
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    @fixnum.send(name, *args, &block)
  end
end

m = MyFixnum.new(1.3)
m.to_i
# => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are `Fixnum` objects for every (and **only**) integer value. No other objects should be created. Therefore inheriting from `Fixnum` is, probably, not a good idea.

You may want to use *composition* instead:

```
class TestClass
    attr_reader :num # fixnum
end
```